# Asymptotics of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}\intop_{0}^{t}\frac{f\left(s\right)}{\left(t-s\right)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\alpha\left(t-s\right)}}ds$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I have the following integral
$$I=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}\intop_{0}^{t}\frac{f(t)}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\alpha(t-s)}}ds$$ and I want to show that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}I=f(t)$.

I have tried separating the integral into two intervals, close to $t$ and away from $t$:
$$I=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi a}}\left[\overset{A}{\overbrace{\intop_{0}^{\delta}\frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\alpha(t-s)}}ds}}+\overset{B}{\overbrace{\intop_{\delta}^{t}\frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\alpha(t-s)}}ds}}\right]$$

Then expanding different terms:
\begin{align}A&=\intop_{0}^{\delta}\frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^{3/2}}\left(1-\frac{\alpha x^{2}(t-s)}{4}+\frac{\alpha^{2}x^{4}(t-s)^{2}}{32}+O(t-s)^{3}\right)ds\\B&=\intop_{\delta}^{t}f(s)e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\alpha(t-s)}}\left(\frac{0.375t^{2}}{(-s)^{1/2}}+1.5t(-s)^{1/2}+(-s)^{3/2}+O(t^3)\right)^{-1}ds\end{align}

I am then able to integrate $A$ but not $B$, any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: hint: You may choose $\delta$ to be a function of $x$

Comment: did not think about that, but how would it help with the integration of $B$?

Comment: Yes, $B$ has a denominator that diverges when $s \rightarrow t$ which needs to be controlled and the exponential controls it.

Comment: also, I believe that defining $u=t-s$ will make everything easier to see.

Comment: @user619894 had a typo, the second expansion should be in the denominator, the divergence is clear now but I am still not sure how to control it with $\delta(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle g(t)=t^{-3/2}e^{-x^2/(4\alpha t)}$ so that $\displaystyle 
 I(t;x)=\frac x{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}\int_0^tf(s)g(t-s)\,ds$.

Taking Laplace transforms on both sides, we obtain $\displaystyle {\cal L}[I(t;x)]=\frac x{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}{\cal L}[f(t)]{\cal L}[g(t)]$ by convolution.

The Laplace transform of $g$ is a standard integral which is $\displaystyle {\cal L}[g(t)]=\frac{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}xe^{-x\sqrt{s/\alpha}}$.

Thus ${\cal L}[I(t;x)]={\cal L}[f(t)]e^{-x\sqrt{s/\alpha}}$ and we can bring the limit $x\to0$ inside ${\cal L}$ to obtain ${\cal L}[I(t;0)]={\cal L}[f(t)]$ for all $t$.

The Laplace transform is injective so the conclusion follows.